# Access variable element of an array in PHP form

Tags: php, forms

If I have in one form

```
<form action="anotherform.php" name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="carga[]" value="3.37">
<input type="checkbox" name="carga[]" value="3.37">
<input type="checkbox" name="carga[]" value="3.37">
<input type="checkbox" name="carga[]" value="3.37">
<input type="submit" value="send" name="send">
</form>
```

and anotherform.php :

```
if (isset($_POST["carga"])){
$cargaacademica=$_POST["carga"];
}
```

How can I access to  the value of carga[0],carga[1],carga[2]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get result using index of your array

```
   echo $_POST["carga"][0];
   echo $_POST["carga"][1];
   echo  $_POST["carga"][2];
```

and so on...
if you want assign to var like

```
$cargaacademica=$_POST["carga"];
```

then try

```
$cargaacademica[0];

$cargaacademica[1];
```

and so on..

Comment: it don't matter if the array is assigned to a variable?

Comment: $cargaacademica=$_POST["carga"];

Answer (score 0):

Since `$_POST['carga']` is already an array that means you are trying to access elements of a multidimensional array for multidimensions array you'd access it as

```
$_POST['carga'][0];
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve with the following loop :

```
for($i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['carga']); $i++ ) {
    echo $_POST['carga'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
foreach($_POST['carga'] as $carga) {
    echo $carga;
}
```

and one more thing,
do not access $_POST directly.

use filter-input

> > http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

$carga = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'carga');